# WSO2 Identity Server using photo-editor UMA webapp

Tags: wso2, sample, wso2-identity-server

I am using **WSO2 5.9.0**

I deployed the photo-edit and photo-view samples as described [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/deploying-the-sample-app/#deploying-the-photo-editor-and-photo-viewer-webapps) and Service providers created successfully. I also setup the three users following the notes.

I start **Tomcat Server** and I reach photo-edit app. I login with Lily's credentials (admin user) and the next step is to approve username sharing.

I choose approve once and continue and here is my issue. Nothing happen until session expires. I tried to check tomcat logs but i can't find any helpful information.

I had deployed the **Playground2** in the past and authentication point works fine. I also try to change callback URL throw **WSO2** dashboard (photo-edit service provider) but i get the same callback URL error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please check the Identity Server console for any error messages? If there are any please add them to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately no error messages.

Comment: Can you please check the tomcat log also when starting?